# Understanding eglCreateWindowSurface()

Tags: android, opengl-es

There's a set of these `eglCreate*Surface` APIs to create *surface*s in Android, I understand that API like `eglCreatePbufferSurface` create a backing buffer which can be rendered with GL calls, but I can't wrap my head around this one, `eglCreateWindowSurface(EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig cfg, Object window, ...)`, if I pass a `Surface` as the window, how could the system make what I draw using OpenGL on the window surface appear on the screen? I know it couldn't, because it doesn't even have a place in the layout in my Activity.

My confusion is if what I draw to the window surface doesn't appear *automatically* on the screen, why it ever exists? isn't it the same as the pixel buffer surface created with `eglCreatePbufferSurface`?

In the 3rd paragraph of this [doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-egl-opengl), which states:

> From that point onward, rendering to that EGLSurface results in a buffer being dequeued, rendered into, and queued for use by the consumer. (The term "window" is indicative of the expected use, but bear in mind the output might not be destined to appear on the display.)

which confuses me more.

Answer (score 1):

> if I pass a `Surface` as the window, how could the system make what I draw using OpenGL on the window surface appear on the screen?

If you don't pass a valid operating system level native window handle as the `native_window` parameter of `eglCreateWindowSurface` it will throw an error. In short, if you pass junk into an API don't expect it to do anything sensible.

Comment: I was not saying to pass junk as the window parameter to it. Since `eglCreateWindowSurface` accepts `Surface` as its 3rd parameter, and I can create a `Surface` using `new Surface(new SurfaceTexture(textureId))`, then what does it mean when I do that? I didn't associate the Surface with any view, what's the difference between `eglCreateWindowSurface` and `eglCreatePbufferSurface` in this case?

Comment: Accepting a non-window surface into eglCreateWindowSurface is Android-specific, and definitely not portable.  Other operating systems will expect a real native_window type, and throw an error if you don't give one.

Answer (score 1):

> My confusion is if what I draw to the window surface doesn't appear automatically on the screen, why it ever exists? isn't it the same as the pixel buffer surface created with eglCreatePbufferSurface?

`eglCreateWindowSurface` and `eglCreatePbufferSurface` both create rendering surfaces, I think the difference is `eglCreateWindowSurface` needs an on-screen native platform window as parameter, which is the main purpose of EGL, connect the native platform window system with OpenGL ES.